# Is there a way to get a Query from an XML file in the format of a String?

Tags: java, sql, xml, spring, spring-boot

I have some XML files with multiple named queries defined in them and everything works fine.

The problem is that I'm doing a more complex query and I would like to know if it's possible to get that query in the format of a string in my code. Right now, I'm getting the queries from the files like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("queryName", className.class);
query.setParameter(PARAMETER_NAME, parameter);
query.setParameter(PARAMETER_NAME, parameter);
```

So what I wanted to do was basically instead of using the **createNamedQuery()** method I wanted to know how I could get the "queryName" query from my xml file.
I will leave here my xml with the query ommited for brevity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

 <named-native-query name="queryName"
                     result-class="className">
        <query>
          **query ommited for brevity**
        </query>
    </named-native-query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the query to the Hibernate `Query` interface:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("queryName");
org.hibernate.query.Query hibernateQuery = query;
```

And then call `getQueryString()`

```
String queryString = hibernateQuery.getQueryString();
```